Should add cap between Emitter and antenna coaxial (J1 in my schematic) to remove DC?
The following is my circuit schematics.


I would do that.

@Andyaka What value should the cap be? Any recommendation?

One with a reactance less than 5 ohm would be a rule of thumb.

Looking at your schematic and the tank values, I would estimate that your oscillator (formed around T2) is running at about 100 MHz. At this frequency you should be adding supply decoupling as well as an output capacitor. I reckon the output capacitor should be greater than 220 pF (reactance of 7.2 Ω).
The added output capacitor prevents amps of current flowing through the tank inductor should the coaxial cable connected to the output become shorted out.
But you also appear to have a problem with C9. It looks like it connects between the output (Q2C node) and ground. It appears to have a value of 0.1 μF and this is not right at all. A value of 10 pF might be more appropriate if the output feeds some form of antenna.
I would also be keen to establish what the DIP switch open circuit capacitance is too. Typically it'll be around 5 pF and although you may be adjusting one trimmer to set the operating frequency, the other trimmer will still have some effect via it's open-circuit DIP switch.

How about the dip switch when both of them are closed? DO they still have capacitance of 5 pF?

What value of decoupling cap do you suggest for VCC and Ground?

@kile up to around 100 MHz, 10 nF caps are OK but, make sure you double check it's not above its self resonance. If it is, go for a 1 nF: https://www.murata.com/-/media/webrenewal/products/emc/emifil/knowhow/basic/chapter06-p6/chapter06-p6_img0001.ashx?la=en-US&cvid=20170911093335296306
